# ASP.NET application login using windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I want to authenticate users when trying to get an application using windows authentication.
I managed to make my application run on windows authentication, but now I want to let only specific users enter. Form authentication is not good for me because I don't want nor need a login page.

So whats the best practice for filtering only specific users? How can people enter the application without the login page?

Thanks, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  xml node, add the  and  configuration modes. Use the users attribute to specify a comma-delimited list of user names. You can use a question mark (?) as a wildcard character that matches any user name.

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="username1, username2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

The above code denies access to all users except `username1` and `username2`. FYI, you can also create roles in the system and allow role based access. Instead of the `users` attribute you use the `roles` attribute.

```
<authorization> 
    <allow roles="Administrators"/> 
    <deny users="*"/> 
</authorization>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: It does help in some way. But what I initially wanted is a method that will be called and allow me to decide the logic if a user is authorized for the application. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: it makes use of windows authetication module(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationmodule.aspx) and its a sealed class so you cannot extend it..

Comment: you could implement you rown IHttpModule... You can make it similar to the WindowsAuthenticationModule and try to add your custom code there, but not sure if thats worth the effort..

Comment: so what is the best practice for a large organization that wants to use windows authentication but wants to implement a custom login? what would you suggest?

Comment: using LDAP is probably the best way